# Nuxt 3 change router base URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I am trying to deploy host/directoryName my Nuxt 3 application.

I added
`app: { baseURL: '/directoryName/‘, }`  into nuxt.config.ts. But, It is not changing. I mean, When I try to access /directoryName/pageName, it is throwing error 404.

Comment: I believe you need to use `useAppConfig()` and pull the base url out from there and then you would be able to construct your url